# Is SchTasks /Delete a synchronous operation?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Is `SchTasks /Delete` a synchronous operation?

OR is it possible that after the `SchTasks` finished and returned a successful error code that there is another task triggering? This would introduce a race condition in our undeployment software.

Unfortunately, we couldn't find any information about it. Does anybody know or have a source where this is stated? Otherwise I have to start ProcExp/ProcMon and find out myself...

Answer (score 0):

It *behaves* as though it is synchronous... I have created and used batch files to import/export/delete scheduled tasks (saved as xml files) using the SchTasks.exe util for several years. I don't have an official statement from Microsoft, but I have never had problems deleting a couple dozen tasks one right after another. I know that when the executable is finished the task is gone.